# SVG polygon render issues

Tags: svg

I am leaning how to create SVG's and am messing about with the Polygon tags.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <polygon points="0,0 0,12.5 12.5,25 0,37.5 0,50 12.5,50 25,37.5 37.5,50 50,50 50,37.5 37.5,25 50,12.5 50,0 37.5,0 25,12.5 12.5,0 0,0 " style="fill: grey; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1px" />
    <polygon points="0,0 0,12.5 12.5,0 0,0" style="fill: red;" onclick="avascript:enlargeiFrame1();" />
    <polygon points="50,0 50,12.5 37.5,0 50,0" style="fill: red;" onclick="javascript:enlargeiFrame2();" />
    <polygon points="50,50 50,37.5 37.5,50 50,50" style="fill: red;" onclick="javascript:enlargeiFrame3();" />
    <polygon points="0,50 0,37.5 12.5,50.5 0,50" style="fill: red;" onlcik="javascript:enlargeiFrame4();" />
</svg>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but when I load it in Chrome, some lines come out thinner than others... is this a known thing? is there a walk around fix for this?

Thanks in advance,

T

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chromium, I guess it depends whats the iFrame code and what specific version you are running, is it the same in other browsers ? (I'm on Chromium  23.0.1271.97 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error, is the same image displayed with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Your problem is that the triangles position overlaps the stroke of your main polygon.

As a workaround, try to add the same first polygon but transparent-filled in front of the other ones, using `fill-opacity:0.0`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <polygon points="0,0 0,12.5 12.5,25 0,37.5 0,50 12.5,50 25,37.5 37.5,50 50,50 50,37.5 37.5,25 50,12.5 50,0 37.5,0 25,12.5 12.5,0 0,0 " style="fill: grey; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1px" />
    <polygon points="0,0 0,12.5 12.5,0 0,0" style="fill: red;" onclick="avascript:enlargeiFrame1();" />
    <polygon points="50,0 50,12.5 37.5,0 50,0" style="fill: red;" onclick="javascript:enlargeiFrame2();" />
    <polygon points="50,50 50,37.5 37.5,50 50,50" style="fill: red;" onclick="javascript:enlargeiFrame3();" />
    <polygon points="0,50 0,37.5 12.5,50.5 0,50" style="fill: red;" onlcik="javascript:enlargeiFrame4();" />    
    <polygon points="0,0 0,12.5 12.5,25 0,37.5 0,50 12.5,50 25,37.5 37.5,50 50,50 50,37.5 37.5,25 50,12.5 50,0 37.5,0 25,12.5 12.5,0 0,0 " style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1px; fill-opacity:0.0;" />    
</svg>
```

Or simply adjust the triangles positions.